# Weighted, Paired-Sample T-test? in R

Tags: r, t-test, paired-comparisons, paired-data, weighted-data

In R you can run a paired t-test (e.g. `t.test(x, y, paired=TRUE)`) as well as a weighted t-test (e.g. `wtd.t.test(x, y, weight=myVectorOfWeights)`), but what about a weighted, paired t-test? `t.test` has no weights argument, `wtd.t.test` has no pairing argument, and I'm unable to find other alternatives. I have a dataset where I need to run such a test -- would appreciate it if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Asking for R code is off topic here. That said, I note that [the documentation reads](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/weights/docs/wtd.t.test) "wtd.t.test produces either one- or two-sample t-tests comparing weighted data". A paired t-test is a one-sample t-test on differences.

Comment: @gung Ok -- so, for example, just run `wtd.t.test( x-y, weight=myVectorOfWeights)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A paired $t$-test is a one-sample $t$-test on differences.  If you have two variables, such as `before` and `after` or `right_side` and `left_side`, you can compute the differences yourself easily (in R it would be: `dif = after - before`).  Then you can run a one-sample $t$-test on those differences.  Your null hypothesis is just that the mean of the differences is $0$.